# Discord.js - Node process terminates prematurely

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm running this very simple node.js application on my RaspberryPi-3.
It's a very basic bot using the [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/) API.

I'm running the program with the script `node index.js >> output.log`.

The problem I'm having is that when leaving the process over night, it always ends up terminating. (No one is using the bot during the night)

Is there some kind of timeout timer in the discord.js or node.js API? 
If not, why is the process terminating?

**Edit1:** 
Turns out this might be a [known bug](https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/issues/1233).

Comment: I'd advise using the process module to log the stack to the console, or use it to detect different types of exits and log them yourself. That is a pretty basic thing to do in any Node enviroment.

Comment: Are there any errors you get? That would be helpful.

Comment: @Tvde1 Nope, however this question is almost a year old now. I moved on from this project a long time ago after it was made clear by the `discord.js` devs to indeed be a bug. (if I'm not mistaken the bug has since been resolved)

Comment: Oh dang I didn't see that, I just searched for "discord.js" in the search bar. Whoops!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question that turned out to be a bug in discord.js
It has since been fixed